# how config mongoose connect parameters in Nestjs

Tags: javascript, mongoose, nestjs

in my nestjs application i want to change some connect parameters, with mongoose itself i can do it like this :

```
await mongoose.connect(process.env.DB, {
      readPreference: "primary",
      tls: true,
      tlsAllowInvalidHostnames: true,
      tlsCAFile: "rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem",
});
```

this is my nest database module how can i add those params to this?

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        uri: configService.get('MONGODB_URI'),
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
  ],
})
export class DatabaseModule {
  static forFeature(models: ModelDefinition[]) {
    return MongooseModule.forFeature(models);
  }
}
```

i need set those params so i can connect to my AWS document db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try something like this please:

```
MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
 imports: [ConfigModule],
 connectionName: 'mySampleDB',
 useFactory: async (config: ConfigService) => ({
  uri: config.get<string>('MONGODB_URI'),
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
 }),
 inject: [ConfigService],
})
```